# Anim Player Error

Tags: animation, interface, shortcut

My question is:
I have a Error: Anim PLayer
That happens if i play my scene (ALT+A) (New Scene too)
In Cycles and Blender Game i have the same Error.
For the Render i use the Render Presets

I get this error...

I have tried other versions of Blender but all Versions same problem.

Good to know:
Blender Version: 2.75
Windows-7 64 Bit
AMD Six Core
AMD Radeon HD 7770

Thanks for every Answer :-)

Andre

Comment: What exactly is the error? Could you upload a screenshot or copy/paste the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't an error. It shows it is playing. If you push the button it stops the animation.

Comment: hmm but why did Blender thinks i'm blind and dont see the timeline.....

Answer (score 1):

The [image]
button means animation player has been turned on (<kbd>ALt</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> is shortcut, press again to turn off).

You can see whether animation is playing looking at the frame numbers in the bottom left of the *3D View*:

[image]

Note numbers in the bottom left change and sometimes become orange - that's the keyframe of the selected object is on adjacent frame.

The simplest way to see the timeline is to switch [screen layout](http://www.blender.org/manual/getting_started/basics/interface/screens.html?highlight=layout) from *Default*  to *Animation*, the timeline will be in the bottom.